# How to mount dynamic disks in Fedora

Tags: linux, multi-boot, fedora, redhat-enterprise-linux, dynamic-disk

I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Fedora. One of my drives I made into a dynamic disk without knowing the consequences. It is a drive I use exclusively for storage so I would like to know how I would go about mounting the drive. Also I would like to mount it at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using ldmtool to make the drive mountable

There is an application called `ldmtool` which allows dynamic disks to be mounted like a normal drive. To install it use:

`# dnf install libldm`

After installing run the command:

`# ldmtool create all`

This will find all dynamic disks on the machine and map it under `/dev/mapper/`

### Mounting the drive

First make a directory for the mount point:

`# mkdir /mnt/somewhere`

Then use `blkid` to find where the drive is mapped to:

`# blkid`

The dynamic disk block device will start with "ldm_". Now you can mount it like you do any other drive. Example:

`# mount -t ntfs /dev/mapper/<your ldm volume> /mnt/somewhere`

### Mounting at boot

To mount at boot first you must create a service for the ldmtool which will allow it to run at boot time. To do this you must create a `.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system`. In this example I will create the file and open it up using nano:

`# nano /etc/systemd/system/ldm.service`

This is the configuration I used to create the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Local Data Manager
Before=local-fs-pre.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ldmtool create all
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After you make the service you must enable it:

`# systemctl enable ldm`

Now the drive is ready to be mounted using fstab. There are different ways of mounting using fstab, the way I recommend is by finding the UUID. This can be found using `blkid`. Once you have the UUID you can add a line to fstab to mount the drive at boot:

`# nano /etc/fstab`

Example configuration:

`UUID=4E0EE2900EE26FFF /mnt/d ntfs-3g defaults,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

Now simply reboot and the drive should be automatically mounted.

### References

- https://www.benholcomb.com/systemd-script-for-ldm/
- https://itso.dk/?p=93
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_disks
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab